# php issue with php-oara library

Tags: php

I download the php-oara from github. I put daisycon credentials in credentials.ini. Then i try to access the affjet.php by using this url localhost/php-oara/examples/affjet.php
but it is showing blank page. My affjet.php code is like this

```
 <?php 


require realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../settings.php';

$arguments = Oara_Utilities::arguments($argv);
$argumentsMap = array();

$argumentsNumber = count($arguments['arguments']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $argumentsNumber; $i++) {

    $argumentsMap[$arguments['flags'][$i]] = $arguments['arguments'][$i];
}

if (isset($argumentsMap['s']) && isset($argumentsMap['e']) && isset($argumentsMap['n'])) {
    //Retrieving the credentials for the network selected
    $config = Zend_Registry::getInstance()->get('credentialsIni');
    $iniNetworkOption = strtolower($argumentsMap['n']);
    $credentials = $config->$iniNetworkOption->toArray();

    //Path for the cookie located inside the Oara/data/curl folder
    $credentials["cookiesDir"] = "example";
    $credentials["cookiesSubDir"] = "Affjet";
    $credentials["cookieName"] = "test";

    //The name of the network, It should be the same that the class inside Oara/Network
    $credentials['networkName'] = $argumentsMap['n'];
    //Which point of view "Publisher" or "Advertiser"
    $credentials['type'] = "Publisher";
    //The Factory creates the object
    $network = Oara_Factory::createInstance($credentials);

    Oara_Test::affjetCli($argumentsMap, $network);
} else {
    fwrite(STDERR, "Usage: affjet [-s startDate] [-e endDate] [-t type] [-n network]\n"."\n"."  NB: Please check you have entered your credentials in your credential.ini before you run this script."."\n"."   Parameters:\n"."\n"."       -s  startDate with format dd/MM/yyyy (11/06/2011)\n"."      -e  endDate with format dd/MM/yyyy (11/06/2011)\n"."        -n  network name of the Oara_Network class for the network (AffiliateWindow, BuyAt, Dgm, WebGains......)\n"."       -t  type this param is not compulsory, choose which report we want, by default it will show us all of them (payment, merchant, transaction, overview)\n"."\n"." Examples from command line:\n"."\n"."       php affjet.php -s 12/02/2010 -e 15/06/2011 -n TradeDoubler\n"."     php affjet.php -s 12/02/2010 -e 15/06/2011 -n TradeDoubler -t merchant\n"."     php affjet.php -s 12/02/2010 -e 15/06/2011 -n AffiliateWindow -t payment\n");
}
```

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: where you are including your file and what is the code?

Comment: did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with using credentials.ini file, therefore it would be better if you test it with credentials attained programmatically from the database or hardcoded into the generic.php file.

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337683/how-to-get-reports-from-amazon-affiliate). It might be useful if you have a look at that question with answer.